# iOS call soap functions in thread

Tags: ios, web-services, soap, nsthread, sudzc

guys

I'm a new iOS developer, I'm having a problem when calling soap functions in new thread.

Here is more details:

I have a function calling soap web service:

```
WebService *webService = [[[WebService alloc]init]retain];
[webService getUser:self action:@selector(getUserHandler) userName: usnm  encPassword: pswd];
```

This function is simply generated from sudzc.com(Great Website! Thanx!)
simply calling this function I can get

```
<user><username>XXX</username><userStatus>XXX</userStatus><companyCode>XXX</companyCode><password>XXX</password></user>
```

back from webservice. and my getUserHandler will work perfectly.

but if I want to call the webservice in a thread like this:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(myMethod) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

-(void)myMethod
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"!, %@,%@",usnm,pswd);
    WebService *webService = [[[WebService alloc]init]retain];
    [webService getUser:self action:@selector(getUserHandler) userName: usnm  encPassword: pswd];
    [pool drain];
}
```

I don't seem to get the returnxml, and it seems the getUserHandler never starts(I put a NSLog in the getUserHandler, but it won't print this time).

I got no idea why is this happening,

any hints are welcome!

Thanx!

Comment: I hear about try asynchronous, is that a good direction? Cause I can't find any examples about calling soap function in that way

Comment: Why not use Grand Central Dispatch?  And, you're over-retaining `webService`...that's going to leak unless you already realise you'll need to `release` it twice and do so.

Comment: Thanks @GarlicFries cause I was tring not to let the autorelease pool release my "webService"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend you to look into the Sync-Async pattern as described in the tutorial here:

[Sync-Async Pair Pattern – Easy concurrency on iOS](http://blog.jayway.com/2011/04/28/sync-asyn-pair-pattern-easy-concurrency-on-ios/)

There is also a question focussing on the same issue:

[Multiple async webservice requests NSURLConnection iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992040/multiple-async-webservice-requests-nsurlconnection-ios)

HTH

Comment: Oh yeah! these 2 links helped me out Thanx!

Comment: Luvina How did u excatly solve this problem?

i have also same problem and i can not find any help