# How can we upload an image in iPhone in a faster manner

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, upload

```
NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageurldata];

NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

[image1 retain];
```

I wrote above code for uploading the image in iPhone, and i m showing a new view in which i am showing this image but image takes time to appear till then the screen is blank. We are taking the image from url and storing it in an object. Is there any to show the image and view at the same time?

Comment: Did you mean download an image instead of upload image?

Answer (score 2):

Try this async approach:

```
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSLog(@"Screen %@ - pauseBannerFileImage download starts", self.name);          
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newUrlForImage]]];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"!-Screen %@-!pauseBannerFileImage downloaded", self.name);
            self.imageView.image = image;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

[how to handle tiling of images on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985477/how-to-handle-tiling-of-images-on-the-fly/5986993#5986993).

You will only need the TileImageView classes and  use it(not UIImageView as it handles data downloading asynchronously) as follows....

```
TileImageView *tileImageView  = [[TileImageView alloc]initWithFrame:<myFrameAsPerMyNeeds>];
[tileImageView setTag:<this is the identifier I use for recognizing the image>];
[myImageScrollView addSubView:tileImageView];
[tileImageView startImageDownloading:imageurldata];
[tileImageView release];
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

As far as my knowledge, it will take some time to download the data from server.there is one way for covering the time delay is show the UIActivityIndicatorView  while downloading the image data

Comment: Can you give me an example of UIActivityIndicatorView for solving this issue.

Comment: add the UIActivityIndicator to the UIView.in view did load hide it.While downloading the image show the indicator.After completion of downloading hide it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to initialize the view before it is actually needed so the load may have already occurred by the time a user needs a view.